# Display tooltips dynamically

Tags: html, css

Html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tooltips</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tooltips.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li tabindex="1">
      <span class="name">Capacity: 1.5 </span>
      <div class="tooltip">
    <p><strong>Some text</strong></p>
    <p>Some long long long  long long long  long long long  long long long  long long long  text</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
li { position : relative; }

div.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 120px;
    width: 24em;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: #fffdc3 top left repeat-x; 
}
```

How can I use hover-event of li to set div property (without js)?  Something like:

```
li:hover -> div.tooltip { display : block; }
li:focus -> div.tooltip { display : block; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. Your final selector is just a little confused.

http://jsbin.com/oholo5/

Answer (score 2):

`li:hover .tooltip{
    display: block;
}`

Answer (score -2):

You can use jquery for displaying tool tips [JQuery Tool Tip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) Its easy to use